# When travelling to Europe from India where should I buy my winter gear?

Tags: shopping, poland, clothing, winter, fra

I am travelling to Germany, Poland and Spain in February this year, from India. It's going to be pretty chilly there and obviously I want to stay warm. I'm not sure where to get my winter gear. I am looking for a decently priced durable Jacket and maybe a shawl. In India, the options are limited. Decathlon has some decent gear, but everything else is super expensive, as we don't really have a lot of snow/winter in the South where I come from. I'm flying via Frankfurt into Wrocław.

Should I wait till I get to Wrocław to get my gear or should I buy it from Frankfurt Airport?

Or is there a third, better way to get stuff?

Comment: This may be closed as opinion-based but have you considered ordering a set of thermals and a packable down jacket from [Amazon India](http://www.amazon.in/Halifax-Traders-Packable-Puffer-Jacket/dp/B0141E54UQ/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1484075916&sr=8-1&keywords=packable%2Bdown%2Bjacket&th=1&psc=1)? It could be the most affordable, and accessible, option.

Comment: Decathlon is actually a great option. Don't know about Poland but in France or the Netherlands, they are between 1/2 and 1/3 of the price of similar gear from name brands (The North Face, Patagonia, etc.) I own both type of hiking/winter sports gear and, based on this limited sample, I am very happy about Decathlon products, certainly for the price. Some other sports shops in Europe also have distributor brands but that's not going to be very helpful to you in India.

Comment: Two other tips: (1) Unless there is some unusual shop I don't know about in Frankfurt, the airport is highly unlikely to be attractive (you can get good deals on premium/luxury products but not everyday items). (2) Don't pay too much for a super-warm jacket, you can be warm (and have much more flexibility) by thinking in layers, e.g. thermal underwear, a warm fleece and a good jacket (if you go for the warmest options in each category at Decathlon, you would pay something like €150, a fraction of what a premium down jacket costs).

Comment: https://www.thenorthface.com

Comment: Decathlon is the way to go, cheap,affordable, resistant.

Answer (score 6):

I would definitely not buy it on the airport, as @Relaxed mentioned, it's almost certain that such stuff will be overpriced.
Assuming that Wroclaw is your first destination, I would ignore Frankfurt (you won't freeze on the airport), go to Wroclaw and find Decathlon or any other shopping mall there, I'm sure you'll find everything you need in good prices

Comment: Do you have any info about prices in Wroclaw? I've heard that Poland is generally cheaper than the rest of Europe except for maybe Bulgaria.

Comment: Fashion clothing is not always cheaper in Poland, it can be more expensive than in Germany, due to the fact that a lot is imported and Germany imports in bigger amounts.

Comment: @nikjohn often you even have the price tags in both € and zl, and brand stuff costs more or less the same in Germany and Poland, maybe slightly (as in 1 or 2 €) more in Poland due to the import issues that were already mentioned